# How do I create a mirror for Eclipse Indigo SR2 (3.7.2)?

Tags: eclipse, mirror, p2

When I tried to update Eclipse to the latest SR2, I got a download rates around 10kb/s - which means I couldn't even get the `content.jar`. Which means I need to setup a mirror for the other 10 developers.

What is the most simple (= less than one day of work) and reliable (= automatic, scripted) way to do this?

Note: Answers which point to the [p2 mirror Ant task](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_mirror.html) won't be accepted unless they come with a complete build script which contains all the IUs and versions necessary to mirror only 3.7.2 or the smallest amount of extra garbage.

What I tried so far: I created a "target definition" and exported that. This contains references to the Java EE EPP. When I add that, I get errors because only one platform may be installed.

I also get errors that `org.eclipse.emf.ecore.change` can only be installed once.

Comment: Could you define better what you are considering "Eclipse 3.7.2"? Just the platform? All traditional Eclipse components (platform + jdt + pdt + cvs)? Anything else (emf, gef, wtp)?

Comment: I'm mostly interested in JDT but we also have some EMF and Xtext components. My hope is that an explanation how to mirror just the update packages for JDT 3.7.2 will give me an idea how to do it for other packages.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're asking for a bit much of someone to assemble a list of just the most recent IUs in the Indigo repository (if that's what you're asking). There's a TON of stuff included in Indigo repo.

What I did was mirror the "staging" repository by executing a command like this:

`/eclipse -nosplash -verbose -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication -source http://download.eclipse.org/releases/maintenance/ -destination file:/Users/eric/Downloads/Eclipse/3.7.2-repo`

It took a few hours and a little less than 2GB of disk space, but it's the simplest way to get a local copy of the repo. I don't know if it's any smaller than the "official" Indigo repository.

Note, that source URL is somewhat transient; it could be cleaned or removed any time soon since the SR2 release is out and pushed to the production Indigo repo (http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo)

[**Update**] The Ant task has a "latestVersionOnly" option that might be just what you're looking for. Coincidentally, I just saw this example the other day: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/295272/809369/#msg_809369

Comment: I'd think that "give me a list of most recent additions" to a p2 repo is a pretty common scenario. The p2 installer has to do it all the time :-/

Comment: I just edited my answer with a link to an example build XML file that might get you going in the right direction.

Comment: `latestVersionOnly` is a moving target - if another developer runs the same script in a couple of months, he might get a different result.

Comment: You said you wanted to set up a mirror for other developers. If you're setting up the mirror, why is there a concern that "someone else will run the same script?" The way most teams seem to do this is to set up one local/internal mirror for their team and everyone is configured to hit that instead of the standard eclipse.org update sites.

Comment: By the way, I usually don't update my existing installations for service releases. I just download the newest package, which is faster because you don't have p2 doing all that reconciliation and resolution work, and you're making a single HTTP request rather than dozens or hundreds. And with the somewhat-new ability to install features from another local Eclipse installation, it's no big deal to re-install third-party plugins/features into the newly downloaded SR.

Comment: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FwhatsNew%2Fplatform_whatsnew.html (click the Install/Update Changes link to jump to the relevant section).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the large online repository, individual Eclipse projects publish their individual deliverables in archived (zip) repositories that you can download and use locally just like you would an online repository. This gives you means to download just what you need, but you will need to deal with multiple separate repositories when updating. If you want to learn a bit of p2 scripting, you can merge these repositories yourself. Either way would work as Eclipse can update from multiple repositories simultaneously.

To find the archived repositories published by various Eclipse projects, start with project's download page.

For instance, for the original "Eclipse" project (which includes JDT), you would go to this page:

http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/

From there, find the appropriate release. Here is 3.7.2:

http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.7.2-201202080800/index.php

Then look for links with terms like "repo", "p2repo" or "UpdateSite". For instance, here is the JDT one:

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.7.2-201202080800/org.eclipse.jdt-3.7.2.zip

Hope this helps.